# Using Python regex for twitter data

Tags: python, regex, twitter

I'm filtering tweets in my application and want to return all tweets that either have a certain word in the text. So if I am filtering BBC and I want all instances of BBC eg. BBC, bbc, BBC1, #BBC, @bbc, how could I write the regex.

So far I'm doing:

```
re.compile(r'#|@[0-9]'+term, re.IGNORECASE)
```

Term is a list containing words and I want returned only those words in the list with the extra @ or # or 0-9 prepending or appending that word OR the word by itself.

Thanks

Comment: The plus sign should probably be *outside* the brackets...

Comment: If I do that, I get this error: "Encountered Exception: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'"

Comment: Outside the *brackets* not outside the quotes! It's still part of the regex...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `'\b'` delimiter to find whole words:

```
re.compile(r'\b(?:#|@|)[0-9]*%s[0-9]*\b' % re.escape(term), re.IGNORECASE)
```